# Area of a surface confined by a sphere II

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, isoperimetric-problems

[A followup on two related posts:
[Area of a surface confined by a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352789/area-of-a-surface-confined-by-a-sphere)

[Area of a elliptic surface confined by a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352820/area-of-a-elliptic-surface-confined-by-a-sphere)

. Thanks to all the inputs so far.]

Let $S$ be a surface enclosed inside the unit sphere in $R^3$. If

1. every point of $S$ is elliptic and
2. there is a point $p$ inside the unit sphere so that every half-ray emanating from $p$ intersects $S$ at most once,

then must it be the case that $\operatorname{Area}(S)\le \operatorname{Area}(S^2)$?

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to ask almost identical question that many times.

Comment: Are your assumptions equivalent with S being a subset of the boundary of a convex body? If so, then the inequality follows e. g. by monotonicity of mixed volumes.

Comment: I think the answer is negative. (See below.) Thanks for your suggestion, that is indeed what I think I need.

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions in the question do not imply that the convex hull of S and p has S as part of its boundary. Moreover, I believe that the two conditions do not imply the desired conclusion. Here is a counterexample to the 1-D version of the question; it seems obvious how to extend it to the 2-D case.

The outer part of the red curve is almost as long as the circle, it makes a sharp turn to add a lot of lengths but without violating either condition.

In the 2-D case, make a surface with an outer part that is close to the confining sphere, then at a 'slit' the surface makes a sharp turn and adds a flat plate to its outer part.

[image]

p.s. I apologize for posting many similar questions.